# How to random 2 value from php string?

Tags: php, random

How to random 2 value from php string ?

Eg.

```
<?PHP
    $xxx = (aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii,jjj)
?>
```

How to random 2 value from $xxx and add 2 value (Unique) to php variable ?

eg. `$one = "ccc";` ADN `$two = "ggg";`

Answer (score 0):

use `array_rand()` php function like this

```
$result = array_rand($array, 2);
```

it will return you 2 values as `$array[$result[0]] and $array[$result[1]]`, 
if the string is comma(,) separated then you can explode the string by comma in array format

Comment: and 2 value are Unique value ?

Comment: not echo value but it's only echo number ?


`<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$array = array('apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'carrot');
$result = array_rand($array , 2);
echo $result[0]; 
echo "<br>";
echo $result[1];
?>`

Comment: its actually array keys, you can use it like $array[$result[0]] and $array[$result[1]]

Comment: it's OK ^^

but when i try to add php variable in to array , it's not echo 


`<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$php_var = "'apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'carrot'";
$array = array($php_var); 
$result = array_rand($array , 2); 
echo $array[$result[0]];  
echo "<br>"; 
echo $array[$result[1]]; 
?>`

Comment: you need to split the string using php explode() function